# Start key + p moniters both went blank

Tags: windows-10

I was messing around and hit the start key + p and selected the single moniter and they both went blank now im stuck and i dont know how to put it back. Help please

Comment: Have you tried restarting the computer? It's possible a forced restart might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's 'presentation display mode' Press it again to choose a different mode.
It should cycle between modes with each press.

From [Wikipedia - Windows Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key)

> <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>   <kbd>P</kbd>  toggles between the devices that receive video card's output. The default is computer monitor only. Other options are video projector only, both showing the same image and both showing a portion of a larger desktop.